# How to get rid of the white shadow in dark mode in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, interface-builder, swift5

I am making a macOS app in Swift and am seeing a weird issue when I switch b/w light and dark modes. The shadow that appears around the image on the light mode is great but the one I am getting by default on the dark mode doesn't look nice. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am getting the same for all other UI elements like Checkboxes, Radio Buttons, etc.

> [image: Shadow in Dark Mode]
>
> *Not nice*

> [image: Shadow in Light Mode]
>
> *Nice*

**Note:**

1. This image is added via the Interface Builder in Xcode.
2. I have the shadow checkbox unchecked as well. See below:
   [image: Shadow Checkbox in IB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the superviews of your view don't define a shadow either or that it has an opaque background.

If your superview doesn't have an opaque background, child views will also have a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try implementing [viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/2977088-viewdidchangeeffectiveappearance) on your `NSView` or do key-value observations on `NSApp.effectiveAppearance`. This way you'll be notified about appearance changes between light/dark mode so you can react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether a view is Dark Mode or not. And you hide shadow when in dark mode.

1. Add an extension to `NSView`:

```
extension NSView {
    
    func isDarkMode() -> Bool {
        if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            return effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.darkAqua, .aqua]) == .darkAqua
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

2. Create a custom view (view, button etc). Override `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance` method in your custom view and update layer.

```
class CustomView: NSView {
    
    override func viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance() {
        // edit shadow's properties. ex: shadowOpacity.
        if isDarkMode() {
            // dark mode
        } else {
            // light mode
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, I was looking for an easier solution, probably in IB itself, as I have too many UI elements added via IB and all of them have this weird shadow in dark mode by default. Not sure why Apple does it. Is the same happening with y'all?